# SQL Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execute

So here is the code for the stored procedure and my execution. I keep getting this message when I try to execute my command:

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_LabelFilm, Line 0
>   Procedure sp_LabelFilm has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Any idea why? I am trying to update a column in the table tblfilm to say if a movie is short, medium, or long based on its run time.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_LabelFilm]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Minutes INT, @duration char(10)

    DECLARE Filmcursor CURSOR FOR 
        (SELECT filmruntimeminutes, Duration FROM tblFilm)

    OPEN filmcursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM filmcursor INTO @duration

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Minutes = FilmRunTimeMinutes FROM tblFilm

        IF @Minutes < 120 
            SET @duration = 'short' 
        ELSE IF @Minutes < 150
            SET @duration = 'medium'
        ELSE
            SET @duration = 'long'

        FETCH NEXT FROM filmcursor INTO @duration

        UPDATE tblFilm 
        SET Duration = @duration
    END

    CLOSE filmcursor
    DEALLOCATE filmcursor
END



DECLARE @Minutes INT, @duration CHAR(10)

EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_LabelFilm] @minutes, @duration
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the error means exactly what it says.  That you are passing arguments (variables `@minutes` and `@duration`) but there are no parameters defined on the stored procedure.

To declare parameters (input variables) you actually declare them before the `AS` like so:

```
use Movies
go

alter PROC [dbo].[sp_LabelFilm]
    @Minutes INT
    ,@duration CHAR(10)
AS

BEGIN


DECLARE Filmcursor  CURSOR 
......
```

Notice you don't need to use the key word `DECLARE` and once they are a declared as parameters you don't actually need to declare them again.

Next I am not totally sure what you are attempting to accomplish with the parameters in the stored procedure but it actually looks like you don't want to pass them but rather you want to get them as out put which would be like this:

```
use Movies
go

alter PROC [dbo].[sp_LabelFilm]
    @Minutes INT OUTPUT
    ,@duration CHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN


DECLARE Filmcursor  CURSOR 
....
```

And your execution statement would look like this:

```
declare @Minutes INT, @duration char(10)
execute [dbo].[sp_LabelFilm] @minutes = @Minutes OUTPUT, @duration = @duration OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

I had defined the parameters on the stored procedure, before the AS, but still I was facing the same problem until I realized that the procedure had 'create' instead of 'alter'. Changing it to alter procedure worked for me.(Faced this issue while I was trying to debug).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the first answer which is apt - In my case I did not have any parameters and while EXEC was getting a similar error.

However the difference being - I was putting a "go" below the EXEC statement.

After removing the go it was executed properly.

Comment: Similar, i had a subsequent stored procedure call, but I did not have exec in front of the subsequent sp call.  So the parser interpreted that sp as an argument to the prior sp, which does not have any parameters....

Answer (score 0):

If you got an error like this while executing a Stored Procedure (SP), just put the schema name before SP name.

For e.g.

```
EXEC [DBO].[stored_procedure_name]
```

and just run. You will get the desired result.